# Get entire row excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have the first cell in the row saved as a range and I just wanted to know how I would go about bringing in the whole row so I would be able to compare the two. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub crossUpdate()
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, N As Long, C As Long
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
Set rng1 = Sheet1.Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)
C1 = rng1.Rows.Count
Set rng1 = Sheet2.Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)
C2 = rng2.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To C


End Sub
```

Comment: Which line in the above code do you believe saves a single cell as a range?

Comment: This line is a typo: `Set rng1 = Sheet2.Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)`, should be `Set rng2 = ...`, right?

Comment: Right. those two lines save the range starting at the second row all the way down to the last populated column on two separate sheets.  I want to use the for loop I started to write to bring in each entire row and compare them from each sheet.

Comment: OK, give me a second I am writing an answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

I notice a typo in your code, as indicated in the comments you're double-assigning to the `rng1` variable, change the second to `Set rng2 = ...`

You have a loop `For i = 2 to C` but you have never assigned anything to the variable `C`, so that will not cause an error, but it will fail to do what you hope it will do.

```
Option Explicit 'use this to force variable declaration, avoids some errors/typos
Sub crossUpdate()
'Declare each variable separately, it is easier to read this way and won't raise problems
' in some cases if you need to pass to other subs/functions
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim N As Long

'Add these declarations
Dim C As Long
Dim R as Long
'I deleted declarations for i (replaced with R), C, N which won't be needed. And also C1, C2

'I'm going to declare some additional range variables, these will be easier to work with
Dim rng1Row as Range
Dim rng2Row as Range
Dim cl as Range

N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
Set rng1 = Sheet1.Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)

Set rng2 = Sheet2.Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)  'This line was incorrect before


'Now to compare the cells in each row

For R = 2 to rng1.Rows.Count
    Set rng1Row = rng1.Cells(R,1).EntireRow
    Set rng2Row = rng2.Cells(R,1).EntireRow

    For C = 1 to rng1.Columns.Count
        If rng1Row.Cells(R,C).Value <> rng2Row.Cells(R,C).Value Then
            'Do something if they are NOT equal
        Else
            'Do something if they ARE equal
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

There are actually some simpler ways to do this, probably, but for purpose of demonstration it is easier for me to explain by breaking it down like this.  But for example, range's aren't limited by the number of cells they contain.  Consider this:

```
Debug.Print Range("A1").Cells(,2).Address
```

Should this raise an error? After all, `[A1]` is a *single* cell.  It won't raise an error, and instead it will correctly print: `$B$1`.

So you could probably simplify to this, and avoid using the `rng1Row` and `rng2Row` variables:

```
For R = 2 to rng1.Rows.Count
    For C = 1 to rng1.Columns.Count
        If rng1.Cells(R,C).Value <> rng2.Cells(R,C).Value Then
            'Do something if they are NOT equal
        Else
            'Do something if they ARE equal
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```